# Scalaz code highlighted with red in Intellij Idea 12 and 13

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, scalaz

We have a project with Play framework 2 coded with Scala. We are using Scalaz for validation in Play controllers like "validateSomething |@| validateSomethingElse |@| validateYetSomethingElse". Idea (v.12 and v. 13 ) doesn't recognise for some reason the syntax at all, even though Scalaz imports are fine. Is there anything we could try to do to fix the situation?
It also seems to be making the Idea really laggy and slow when editing the classes sontaining the "unrecognised" scalaz symbols.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. You simply didn't add (the correct version of) Scalaz to the project's libraries. This is the most likely, if all Scalaz symbols are highlighted.
2. IDEA is known to sometimes highlight false errors in Scala code. They are working on it, but this still happens sometimes.