# Cartesian product |@| not working in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-cats, intellij-scala

This compiles just fine with sbt:

```
  val a: ValidatedNel[String, Int] = 10.valid

  a |@| a
```

But in IntelliJ, it shows up as an error:

[image: IntelliJ1]

This makes functional error handling with Cats very inconvenient. All my "IDE-compile-time" typesafety is gone; and it makes the code really painful to work with since intellij will constantly tell you that you've "messed up" (even though the code is perfectly fine).

Is there another way of writing this that doesn't make IntelliJ flip out? For instance, if there was some alias to the `|@|` that intellij understood?

Also, does anyone know *why* IntelliJ doesn't understand the syntax - it perfectly understands the |+| syntax:

[image: Intellij2]

Comment: unfortunately this is a known problem of IntelliJ. Here's a few more references on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679973/controlling-false-intellij-code-editor-error-in-scala-plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773436/scalaz-code-highlighted-with-red-in-intellij-idea-12-and-13

Comment: The first link suggests you turn off all the type-awareness in Intellij which just instantly defeats the purpose of using an IDE. The second just acknowledges that intellij-scala has problems. Neither really helps :(  I need a workaround until they (bother to) fix it.

Comment: yep, those were references to confirm the problem with intellij, not a solution (I would've posted an answer otherwise). I'm not aware of any workaround, sorry.

Comment: Since we're linking things, here's a youtrack ticket for the bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10237

Comment: anyway, a possible reason of *why* `|@|` causes problems and `|+|` does not is that the former is overloaded on several variations of `CartesianBuilder` which are generated by a boilerplate. Probably IntelliJ can't resolve the correct overload.

Comment: see https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/a0aa6e0d307c80652a5805bcf0a6898d77855480/project/Boilerplate.scala#L98-L153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is resolved in the latest IntelliJ-Scala releases:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10237